# What would be the best Linux distro that meet my needs?

Tags: linux, linux-distribution

I am looking to install linux on my pc. I want to get a distro that is not complicated to install like Arch for example, and doesn't have a whole bunch of programs pre-installed like Ubuntu for example.

I have a decent PC: 8th gen Intel 4c 8t processer 8gb RAM. Looking to code, browse the web, zoom. The point is I don't want a browser, media player, python, and other things ubuntu comes with, preinstalled. But I do want a GUI and don't want to work hard to install it.

What would be the right distro to try?

P.S. And will your recommendation change if i want to live boot it?

Comment: Your requirements are strange. You want to browse the web but don't want a browser. And: I don't think there is any GUI OS without a browser. Also python is needed for `apt`, so any Debian-distro is out. Install Ubuntu and remove the software you don't need (leave python!) should be easy enough.

Comment: @pLumo Yeah, should've explained myself better. I don't won't everything to be pre-installed i want to be able to choose the browser i want. Thank you for your idea of uninstalling what i don't need. I asked my question because i don't want that hassle and want to know if there's a better option.

Comment: The first thing i usually run after installing Ubuntu is `sudo apt purge rhythmbox shotwell gedit`, costs me like 10 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

Many OS have a server version that comes with nothing like that installed.
[image]

I skipped a number of non-relevant click next screens.

Click on the search tab, and selected Firefox

[image]
You will be then shown the minimum requirements for, in this case, firefox

Click continue

and you can now install linux with the minimal firefox requirements.
However you could do the same with any browser.

The list is quite long compared to a text based OS that we started with.
Click install and you will have that configuration.

Comment: This is a real interesting answer.  When a user selects the server version, are server components installed that would not be installed if they selected a non-server version?

Comment: Probably a few are, but generally the function of the server  version is not to install much and leave you alone to install whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks.  My thinking (and concern) is that if they install server components, it could possibly open the OS up to unnecessary security issues.  Of course, so can installing unneeded non-server software, but probably to a lesser degree.

Comment: You can always uncheck the components you don't want up to a point.

Comment: Do you know if you can uncheck all the server components that aren't installed in the desktop versions?  If so, the server versions seem ideal for everyone who doesn't want a bunch of extra stuff installed.

Comment: Apparently there is nothing you can't uncheck, except the built-in dependency checker will come back an say hey these components are needed to have a functioning system and you will have to accept that list to proceed.